# Should you assert not null with the assert statement in production code?

Tags: java, assert, nullable

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537609/is-it-good-practice-to-use-assert-in-java) question but have a few more questions about the usage of the `assert` keyword. I was debating with a few other coders about using `assert`. For this use case, there was a method that can return null if certain prerequisites are met. The code I wrote calls the method, then asserts it doesn't return null, and continues to use the returned object.

Example:

```
class CustomObject {
    private Object object;

    @Nullable
    public Object getObject() {
        return (object == null) ? generateObject() : object;
    }
}
```

Now imagine I use it like this:

```
public void useObject(CustomObject customObject) {
    object = customObject.getObject();
    assert object != null;
    // Do stuff using object, which would throw a NPE if object is null.
}
```

I was told I should remove the `assert`, that they should **never** be used in production code, only be used in testing. Is that true?

Comment: By default, assertions are disabled. You have to explicitly enable them at runtime via `-ea` or equivalent.

Comment: Related question on Software Engineering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/137158/187318 (although it is quite old, so the accepted answer there still recommends an external library, which is no longer necessary since the introduction of `Objects.requireNonNull` in Java 8).

Comment: This question title is way overly broad, but the question stated in the body is much more narrow, and per the answers is fully handled by helper-functions.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking whether ***client*** code should implement non-null checks/asserts on objects. (That's different from asking whether the ***library*** code itself should guarantee objects cannot be null, or assert that there).

Comment: *"I was told assert should NEVER be used in production code, only in testing."* Depends on what the expectation of test coverage and correctness is, and very domain-specific (just e-commerce? airplane control?) Is this your library and are you happy with its level of test coverage?

Comment: I believe you are asking about _whether_ assertions should be used in production code, not _how_. Look for articles on the software architecture strategy "fail fast" (aka "fail early").  IMO it has a place in many - but not all! - production environments, and may help you figure out whether assertions are a good idea or not in your particular use cases.

Comment: Also please note that this can be language and community-specific: people use asserts in production code all the time in other languages, especially dynamic languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[When should assertions stay in production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732/when-should-assertions-stay-in-production-code)*

Comment: After more than 11 years and [19,101,075 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest), what is the chance that such a question has not been asked before?

Comment: Almost exact duplicate (as C# is an improved version of Java and/or a case of plagiarism): *['Assert' statements in .NET production code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818999)*

Comment: Tagged with Java (tough more ***can*** than ***should*** / ***should not***): *[Can assertions be used in production or only while developing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985328)*

Comment: Stack Overflow question *[Java assertions underused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298909)* has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298909/java-assertions-underused/54778330#54778330) containing *"This maxim of "**Assertions** aren't generally used in **production code**”, though common, is **incorrect**."* (my emphasis)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`Objects.requireNonNull(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) for that.

> Checks that the specified object reference is not null. This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors, [...]

In your case that would be:

```java
public void useObject(CustomObject customObject) {
    object = customObject.getObject();
    Objects.requireNonNull(object); // throws NPE if object is null
    // do stuff with object
}
```

This function is made for what you want to do: explicitly mark what is not to be `null`. The benefit is that you find `null`-values right where they should not occur. You will have [less troubles debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45632920/12323248) problems caused by `null`s that are passed somewhere where they shouldn't be.

Another benefit is the flexibility when using this function in contrast to `assert`. While `assert` is a keyword for checking a boolean value, `Objects.requireNonNull(Object)` is a function and can be embedded in code much easier.

```java
Foo foo = Objects.requireNonNull(service.fetchFoo());

// you cannot write it in one line.
Bar bar = service.fetchBar();
assert bar != null;
```

```java
service.foo(Objects.requireNonNull(service.getBar()));

// you cannot write it in one line.
Bar bar = service.getBar();
assert bar != null;
service.foo(bar);
```

Keep in mind that `Objects.requireNonNull(Object)` is only for `null`-checking while `assert` is for general assertions. So `assert` has [different purposes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html): primarily testing. It has to be enabled, so you can enable it for testing and disable it in production. Use it to seperate testing-only-tests from tests, or rather checks, that are meant for production-code too.

Comment: Given that you can decide at runtime whether assert operates, but you cannot determine at runtime whether the NPE is thrown by requireNonNull, what do you mean by 'you have more control with it than with assert'?

Comment: @PeteKirkham You are right, *control* was the wrong word for that. I was more talking about the flexibility in syntax. In addition: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632920/why-should-one-use-objects-requirenonnull?noredirect=1&lq=1) can be reasons found why you would want code to throw NPEs.

Comment: "don't use it for production code. It could slow down the application" It could, but it could be worth it. Java has built-in runtime checks for ensuring you never overrun an array. These are enabled even on production deployments, despite the possible performance penalty. We aren't even given a choice about it. It's not always wrong to have runtime checks in production code.

Answer (score 25):

The most important thing to remember about assertions is that they can be disabled, so never assume they'll be executed.

For backward compatibility, the JVM disables assertion validation by default. They must be explicitly enabled using either the `-enableassertions` command line argument, or its shorthand `-ea`:

```
java -ea com.whatever.assertion.Assertion
```

So, it's not a good practice to rely on them.

As assertions aren't enabled by default you can never assume they will be executed when used in the code. So you should always check for null values and empty Optionals, avoid using assertions to check inputs into a public method and instead use an unchecked exception... In general do all the checks as if the assertion wasn't there.

Comment: Obviously bad practice to rely on them, but is it bad practice to use it in general?

Comment: @Big_Bad_E Assertions are a debug tool that exists to make a program fail as early and as noisily as possible. It is then the job of the test suite to ensure that there is no way a program can fail *despite the assertions*. The idea is, once the test suite (it's got 100% coverage, doesn't is?!?) executes without a failure, it's save to remove the assertions as they cannot trigger anyways. Sure there's a bit of idealism in this reasoning, but that's the idea.

Comment: This is so critical to know they are disabled by default and not intended for production. We had some of them in production to prevent a critical issue that should never happen. It went through multiple "fixes" that had an impact during development, but not so in production. At some point we realized they are disabled by default and replaced them with normal exceptions. I wonder how many production systems have them in place for the wrong reason, just because of lack of knowledge :) imo it would be better if they wouldn't exist at all or if the IDE would give hints at least

Answer (score 13):

Surely what you are told is a blatant lie. Here's why.

Assertions are disabled by default if you just execute standalone jvm. When they are disabled, they have zero footprint, hence they will not affect your production application. However, they are probably your best friends when developing and testing your code, and most of testing framework runners enable assertions (JUnit does), so your assertion code is executed when you run your unit tests, helping you detect any potential bugs earlier (e.g. you can add asserts for some business logic boundary checks, and that will help detect some code which uses inappropriate values).

That said, as the other answer suggests, for exactly that reason (they are not always enabled) you cannot rely on assertions to do some vital checks, or (especially!) maintain any state.

For an interesting example of how you could use asserts, have a look [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/impl/single/SingleChronicleQueueStore.java) - at the end of the file there's a method `singleThreadedAccess()` which is called from the assert statement on line 201 and is there to catch any potential multithreaded access in tests.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers already cover this well enough, but there are other options.

For example, Spring has a static method:

`org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(obj)`

There are other libraries with their own `Assert.something()` methods as well. It's also pretty simple to write your own.

However, keep in mind what exceptions you throw if this is a web service. The previous method mentioned, for example, throws an `IllegalArgumentException` which by default in Spring returns a 500.

In the case of a web service, this is often *not* an internal server error, and should not be a 500, but rather a 400, which is a bad request.

Comment: If the "Assert" method does not immediately crash the process, throwing some kind of exception instead, then it's not an assert. The whole point of `assert` is, to get an immediate crash with a core file produced so that you can do a post-mortem with your favorite debugger right at the spot where the condition was violated.

Comment: Asserts don't immediately crash a process. They throw an Error, which may be caught. Unhandled exceptions will crash your tests just as well as errors. You can argue semantics if you want. If you so desire, write a custom assert that throws an Error instead of exception. The fact is, in the overwhelming majority of cases, the appropriate action is to throw an exception rather than an error.

Comment: Ah, Java does indeed define `assert` to throw. Interesting. The C/C++ version doesn't do such a thing. It immediately raises a signal that a) kills the process, and b) creates a core dump. It does this for a reason: It's dead simple to debug such an assertion failure because you still have the entire information about the call stack available. Defining `assert` to throw an exception instead, which may then be caught (un)intentionally programmatically, defeats the purpose, imho.

Comment: Just as there are some (or many) weird things in C and C++, there are some in Java. One of them is `Throwable`. They can always be caught. Whether or not that's a good thing or not, I don't know. I guess it depends. Many Java programs are web services, and it would be undesirable for it to crash for almost any reason, so just about everything is caught and logged. One of the great things is the stack trace, and that's usually enough to diagnose the reason for an exception or error by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Use asserts liberally whenever doing so helps catching *programming* mistakes i.e. bugs.

Do not use assert to catch something that might logically happen i.e. badly formatted input. Use assert only when the error is unrecoverable.

Do not put any production logic in the code that runs when the assertion is checked. If your software is well written this is trivially true but if it's not then you might have subtle side effects and different overall behavior with assertions enabled and disabled.

If your company has "testing code" and "production code" doing the same thing but as different code bases (or different stages of editing), get out of there and never come back. Trying to fix that level of incompetence is probably a waste of your time.
If your company doesn't put any assert statement outside of the code of the tests, kindly tell them that asserts are disabled in the production build and that if they aren't, fixing that mistake is now your first priority.

The value of asserts is precisely to be used inside the business logic and not only the test suite.
This makes it easy to churn out many high level tests that don't have to explicitly test many things to go through big chunks of your code and trigger all these assertions.
In a few of my projects typical tests didn't even really assert anything, they just ordered a calculation to happen based on specific input and this caused hundreds of assertions to be checked and problems to be found even in tiny pieces of logic deep down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use assert any time. The debate come is when to use. For example in [the guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#compiling) :

- Do not use assertions for argument checking in public methods.
- Do not use assertions to do any work that your application requires for correct operation.

Comment: Good rules. But the answer would be better with some reasons added.